# Is it possible to record scenario through a jmeter when server is at remote location

Tags: jmeter

When target server is hosted in local network, then it's possible to record through HTTP proxy. But when server located at remote location, can we do the recording of the scenario through jmeter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference from JMeter's perspective where the application under test is located, JMeter acts like a proxy for a web browser and given web browser is capable of reaching the application under test - JMeter will record the requests so the answer is **yes**

Reference material:

- [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
- [JMeter Proxy Step by Step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
- [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server)